# How to draw axis in an animated format using D3 to create a story line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

We want to show the drawing of the axis in the animated format. So that we highlight the axes between which graph is plotted. This is required to help us in creating a story line for the visualization.

Is it possible using D3(Data Driven Documents)? and if yes then can someone guide us through.

An example of this is included in Hans Rosling's video, The Joy of Stats on youtube.
www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbkSRLYSojo‎

Comment: Hi Lars, http://jsfiddle.net/arnica04/Cxep3/2/ is where you can find the code. I simply want the axis to zoom in and zoom out (animation) before the plotting is done.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "zoom in and zoom out" or "animated format". Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cxep3/3/) for the x axis?